# Cadence activity task not retrying even after providing retry configuration

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

Cadence server version: 0.19.2

I have made following observation: I have a Job workflow that triggers encoding workflow (child workflow) which has an activity to handle encoding status. I have supplied retry configuration and heartbeat configuration in both child workflow and activity in case the workflow or activity fails due to server getting killed. However out of lets say 100 jobs, i get 20 jobs where the activity doesn't retries. It fails in attempt 0 with timeout type heartbeat timeout. I am sharing below parent workflow json and child workflow json and along with the some screen shots

Child workflow JSON
http://jsonblob.com/1007526462865293312

Parent Workflow JSON
http://jsonblob.com/1007526121943875584

[image: Activity configuration]
[image: Child workflow configuration]

Comment: Also why childworkflow didnt retried when workflow execution failed

Comment: @long can you please help with this question? I have the following suspects 1) possible bug in that version of cadence that got fixed later 2) There is some weird race condition happening when the server gets killed and when the cadence client kills workers, and this is solved by enabling auto heartbeat

Comment: Could you share some more details from the child workflow by using the GRID view? There should be some more information about why it failed. It says it failed with HEARTBEAT timeout but I'm guessing activity timeout should have also passed so it wouldn't have retried. GRID view should tell more.